# Converting a Model.bim from SQL Server 2017 to 2019

Tags: ssas, tabular

I am new to tabular and I have created our first SSAS tabular model in 2017 ok and deployed it fine. We have now upgraded our server to 2019 so I am trying to change the Compatibility Level of this to 2019 in VS 2019 but I am getting an error.

**1500 is not a valid value for this element.
An error occurred while parsing the 'ddl200:CompatibilityLevel' element at line 16, column 73 ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200' namespace) under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command/Alter/ObjectDefinition/Database/CompatibilityLevel.**

I have set the default Compatibility Mode of VS to 2019 but I still get the error.

[image]

I have even tried creating a blank 2019 project and adding the  .bim file created in 2017 into it but get an error.

**An error occurred while opening the model on the workspace database. Reason: Tabular databases do not support CompatibilityLevel downgrade.**

Without starting from scratch in 2019 I can't see how I can fix it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a workspace server that doesn't support compatibility level 1500, you will receive that error. Consider updating your workspace SQL Server 2017 to SQL Server 2019 analysis services. Alternatively, you can switch your project to an integrated workspace; then, it will allow you to upgrade to 1500. I have a short post on that [here](https://sqlitybi.com/error-upgrading-ssas-tabular-from-compatibility-1400-to-1500/)